# Optimize a nearest neighbor resizing algorithm for speed

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

I'm using the next algorithm to perform nearest neighbor resizing. Is there anyway to optimize it's speed? Input and Output buffers are in ARGB format, though images are known to be always opaque. Thank you.

```
void resizeNearestNeighbor(const uint8_t* input, uint8_t* output, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
{
    const int x_ratio = (int)((sourceWidth << 16) / targetWidth);
    const int y_ratio = (int)((sourceHeight << 16) / targetHeight) ;
    const int colors = 4;

    for (int y = 0; y < targetHeight; y++)
    {
        int y2_xsource = ((y * y_ratio) >> 16) * sourceWidth;
        int i_xdest = y * targetWidth;

        for (int x = 0; x < targetWidth; x++)
        {
            int x2 = ((x * x_ratio) >> 16) ;
            int y2_x2_colors = (y2_xsource + x2) * colors;
            int i_x_colors = (i_xdest + x) * colors;

            output[i_x_colors]     = input[y2_x2_colors];
            output[i_x_colors + 1] = input[y2_x2_colors + 1];
            output[i_x_colors + 2] = input[y2_x2_colors + 2];
            output[i_x_colors + 3] = input[y2_x2_colors + 3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is optimal in terms of computational complexity. Only cosmetic optimizations can be done here (for example try using memcpy instead of input<-output assignments).

Comment: Since you are assuming four 8-bit channels per pixel anyway, you might improve performance by working directly with elements of type `uint32_t`.  That way you could reduce your four assignment statements in the innermost loop to one, and you could drop a couple of multiplications there, too.  (This fails to help only if the compiler is already performing such an optimization on its own.)

Comment: Note: `x_ratio, y_ratio, y2_xsource, i_xdest` are prone to undetected overflow.

Comment: `x2, y2_x2_colors, i_x_colors` may be simplified as `x` increments by 1 and updated values may be obtained taking advantage of that.  This is similar to the classic [Bresenham line drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).  Sorry - do not have take to dig deeper.

Comment: What CPU are you targeting?  There might be CPU-specific optimizations.  If this was x86/x64, I might question if fixed point is faster than floating point.

Comment: do the last output - input equation first to try some prefetch optimzation.

Comment: Eliminate the multiplies from the loops.

Comment: I'm with @Moby -- those multiplications can be trivially replaced with additions.

Comment: What are your targeted image sizes ? (Please, not "any".)

Comment: For this kind of image processing stuff where you already have some micro-optimizations, your biggest immediate bang for the buck often come from parallelizing the code (ex: parallel for to process each row of the image). Even bigger but more intensive is using GPU. And SIMD can also help, but it's one of the toughest in terms of effort/gain ratio.

Answer (score 1):

`restrict` keyword will help a lot, assuming no aliasing.

Another improvement is to declare another `pointerToOutput` and `pointerToInput` as `uint_32_t`, so that the four 8-bit copy-assignments can be combined into a 32-bit one, assuming pointers are 32bit aligned.

Answer (score 1):

There's little that you can do to speed this up, as you already arranged the loops in the right order and cleverly used fixed-point arithmetic. As others suggested, try to move the 32 bits in a single go (hoping that the compiler didn't see that yet).

In case of significant enlargement, there is a possibility: you can determine how many times every source pixel needs to be replicated (you'll need to work on the properties of the relation Xd=Wd.Xs/Ws in integers), and perform a single pixel read for k writes. This also works on the y's, and you can memcpy the identical rows instead of recomputing them. You can precompute and tabulate the mappings of the X's and Y's using run-length coding.

But there is a barrier that you will not pass: you need to fill the destination image.

If you are desperately looking for speedup, there could remain the option of using vector operations (SEE or AVX) to handle several pixels at a time. Shuffle instructions are available that might enable to control the replication (or decimation) of the pixels. But due to the complicated replication pattern combined with the fixed structure of the vector registers, you will probably need to integrate a complex decision table.

Comment: This approach only applies when enlarging the image, not when shrinking it.  You could make two functions, optimized for each purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is fine, but you can utilize massive parallelization by submitting your image to the GPU. If you use opengl, simply creating a context of the new size and providing a properly sized quad can give you inherent nearest neighbor calculations. Also opengl could give you access to other resizing sampling techniques by simply changing the properties of the texture you read from (which would amount to a single gl command which could be an easy paramter to your resize function).

Also later in development, you could simply swap out a shader for other blending techniques which also keeps you utilizing your wonderful GPU processor of image processing glory.

Also, since you aren't using any fancy geometry it can become almost trivial to write the program. It would be a little more involved than your algorithm, but it could perform magnitudes faster depending on image size.

Comment: "magnitudes faster": what about transfer between memories ? This will be the bottleneck, won't it ?

Comment: That's where it starts becoming hardware dependent. The benefit of taking the GPU route is related to CPU speed : GPU bus speed (depending on the GPU implementation) ratio. If you have a crazy 3-4GHz processor to work with then you may lose a little time to the transfer times, but for slower processors or well implemented GPUs you can shave off a LOT for huge images.

Comment: I still don't see how, as this function is essentially copying source pixels to destination pixels and doing little computation. The bottleneck is main memory speed.

Comment: Also consider parallelization. If you're doing any image processing, it just makes sense to let the gpu handle it and let your cpu think of other brilliant things. In fact, other functional processes like this are encouraged to move to a GPU or processing farm hence openCL is finding it's way into our lives. CPUs should be handling more logical / branching operations while we let our gpus eat through silly numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't break anything.  This combines some of the suggestions posted thus far and is about 30% faster.  I'm amazed that is all we got.  I did not actually check the destination image to see if it was right.

Changes:
- remove multiplies from inner loop (10% improvement)
- uint32_t instead of uint8_t (10% improvement)
- __restrict keyword (1% improvement)

This was on an i7 x64 machine running Windows, compiled with MSVC 2013.  You will have to change the __restrict keyword for other compilers.

```
void resizeNearestNeighbor2_32(const uint8_t* __restrict input, uint8_t* __restrict output, int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
{
    const uint32_t* input32 = (const uint32_t*)input;
    uint32_t* output32 = (uint32_t*)output;

    const int x_ratio = (int)((sourceWidth << 16) / targetWidth);
    const int y_ratio = (int)((sourceHeight << 16) / targetHeight);

    int x_ratio_with_color = x_ratio;

    for (int y = 0; y < targetHeight; y++)
    {
        int y2_xsource = ((y * y_ratio) >> 16) * sourceWidth;
        int i_xdest = y * targetWidth;

        int source_x_offset = 0;
        int startingOffset = y2_xsource;
        const uint32_t * inputLine = input32 + startingOffset;
        for (int x = 0; x < targetWidth; x++)
        {
            i_xdest += 1;
            source_x_offset += x_ratio_with_color;
            int sourceOffset = source_x_offset >> 16;

            output[i_xdest] = inputLine[sourceOffset];
        }
    }
}
```